# No se actualizan los datos de una vista

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un listado de clientes que tengo que actualizar, pero al cambiar los valores, al hacer clic en actualizar, me vuelven a aparecer los datos originales.

Modelo `Cliente`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ejercicio03.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Clase `ClienteServicio`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ejercicio03.Models
{
    public class ClienteServicio
    {
        // INSTANCIAMOS 
        public static List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();

        // CONSTRUCTOR SIN PARAMETROS
        public ClienteServicio()
        {
            // INICIALIZAMOS
            if (lista.Count == 0)
            {
                this.altaCliente(1, "Julian", "Butron");
                this.altaCliente(2, "Pedro", "Picapiedra");
                this.altaCliente(3, "Pablo", "Marmol");
            }
        }

        // CONSTRUCTOR CON PARAMETROS
        public ClienteServicio(int id, string nombre, string apellido)
        {
            this.altaCliente(id, nombre, apellido);
        }

        // GETTER: MOSTRAR LISTA
        public List<Cliente> mostrarCliente()
        {
            return lista;
        }

        // SETTER: ESTABLECER CLIENTE
        public void altaCliente(int id, string nombre, string apellido)
        {
           lista.Add(new Cliente() { id = id, nombre = nombre, apellido = apellido });
        }
    }
```

Vista `Todos`:

```
@Model Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente 

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Todos</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica">
    <a href="Bienvenido"><input type="button" value="Volver" style="margin-left:635px;margin-top:18px;"/></a>
    <div style="width:600px;margin:auto;margin-top:-45px;background-color:#DD0611;color:white;">      
        <h2 style="padding-top:20px;text-align:center;">CLIENTES</h2>
        <a href="AltaCliente"><input type="button" value="Nuevo Cliente" style="margin: 0 0 6px 6px;padding:4px;background-color:#1DAE46;color:white;"/></a>
    </div>
    <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ECEBEB" padding="10px">
        <tr>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Id</th>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Nombre</th>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Apellido</th>
            <th colspan='2' style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Operaciones</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente c in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.id</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.nombre</td>
                 <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.apellido</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="DetalleCliente?id=@c.id"><input type="button" value="Mostrar" /></a></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="EditarCliente?id=@c.id"><input type="button" value="Editar" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Vista `EditarCliente`:

```
@Model Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EditarCliente</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica">
    <div style="width:600px;margin:auto;margin-top:40px;padding:5px;background-color:#DD0611;color:white;box-sizing: border-box;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Editar Cliente</h2>
    </div>
    <form action="EditarCliente" method="post" style="margin:auto;">

        <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ECEBEB" ;margin="0" ;padding="0" ;>
            @foreach (Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente c in Model)
            {
                if (c.id == Convert.ToInt16(Request["id"]))
                {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;padding:3px;">Nombre</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;"><input type="text" name="nombre" value="@c.nombre"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;padding:3px;">Apellido</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;"><input type="text" name="apellido" value="@c.apellido"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="@c.id" /></td>
                <td colspan='2' style="text-align:center;padding:20px;"><input type="submit" value="ACTUALIZAR" style="padding:6px;background-color:#1DAE46;color:white;" /></td>
            </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controlador `Cliente`:

```
using Ejercicio03.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ejercicio03.Controllers
{
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Cliente

        // BIENVENIDO
        public ActionResult Bienvenido()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // LISTADO DE CLIENTES
        public ActionResult Todos()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var listado = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(listado);
        }

        // ALTA CLIENTE
        public ActionResult AltaCliente()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]  // RECIBE LOS DATOS DE LA VISTA "AltaCliente".
        public ActionResult AltaCliente(Cliente c)
        {

            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio(c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido);
            return View("Bienvenido"); // Retorna a la vista "Bienvenido"
        }

        // MOSTRAR DETALLE CLIENTE
        public ActionResult DetalleCliente()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var detalle = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(detalle);
        }

        // EDITAR CLIENTE
        public ActionResult EditarCliente()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var cli = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(cli);
        }

      /*  [HttpPost]  // RECIBE LOS DATOS DE LA VISTA "EditarCliente".
        public ActionResult EditarClienteProc(Cliente c)
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio(c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido);
            return View("Bienvenido");
        }
        */
    }
}
```

¿Qué está pasando?

Comment: Hola Andrés, en tu código no se ve el Action `EditarCliente` en el Controller, ¿no será lo que te está faltando?

Comment: no había agregado el Controller

Comment: Agrégalo y si después de eso sigues teniedo el mismo problema ya revisamos a detalle qué puede estar fallando :)

Comment: me sigue haciendo lo mismo

Comment: En el Controller Cliente, método `public ActionResult EditarCliente()` ¿no deberías direccionar nuevamente a mostrar todos los clientes? Es decir, en lugar de `return View(cli);` debería ser algo como `return RedirectToAction("Cliente", "Todos");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo varios problemas.

Por un lado no tienes implementada la acción que recibe los datos del formulario EditarCliente (o más exactamente la tienes comentada). La implementación podría ser algo así:

```
    [HttpPost]  // RECIBE LOS DATOS DE LA VISTA "EditarCliente".
    public ActionResult EditarCliente(Cliente c)
    {
        ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio(c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido);
        return View("Todos", cs.mostrarCliente());
    }
```

De esta forma, una vez editado el cliente, se redirige al listado completo de clientes.

Por otro lado, cuando llamas al constructor de ClienteServicio con parámetros, siempre realizas un alta de un nuevo cliente. Deberías comprobar si ya existe un cliente con el id (es una edición) o si no existe (es un alta de un nuevo cliente). Algo así:

```
    // CONSTRUCTOR CON PARAMETROS
    public ClienteServicio(int id, string nombre, string apellido)
    {
        var cliente = lista.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            // El cliente no exite
            altaCliente(id, nombre, apellido);
        }
        else
        {
            // El cliente sí existe editamos sus datos
            cliente.nombre = nombre;
            cliente.apellido = apellido;
        }
    }
```

Comment: era eso, muchas gracias